# Best place to load data from service in xamarin forms MVVM

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the best place to call a service and load data in xamarin forms

1. Till now I am calling the service in the view model constructor and loading data
2. I have a new situation -
   In my app I check for network connectivity, if it's not connected to internet I will not load data in the main form and show a modal form saying network is not available check. If the recheck is success will pop the modal but as the data is not loaded the main form is empty.

So in this case I have to write service call in on appearing override function. Which gets called after the modal popped. Which is okay. But problem is every time when we navigate to that view it will make a service call.

Please guide me the best place to call these services

Comment: I would advise **not** to do the service call in the constructor. The constructor is for **initialization**, not really for any heavy operations.

Comment: @MikeEason so the best practice is OnAppearing ? Also in you mean the constructor of view or viewmodel?

Comment: Good question, I have the same question. It is a pity that there aren't more answers.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem, you can use C# Events (Publisher-Subscriber) as the solution
Write a event called InternetDisconnectedEvent in the View Model. Subscribe to that event in Code behind of the View (.xaml.cs)

Make UI Changes in the View, when internet disconnected.

For more about Event & Delegates, [check this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQgwEsJISy0)

Comment: I am not looking for a solution now, I have already implemented. But rather I asking the best place to make a service call load data in to the object declared in view model in xamarin

Answer (score 0):

> *"...But problem is every time when we navigate to that view it will make a service call."*

Create a flag (a boolean property), say `IsLoaded` in the viewmodel (or view, depending on your current implementation), that set to `false` initially. Then add a logic that check `IsLoaded` flag before calling the service. If `IsLoaded` is `false`, run your current logic of checking internet connection, calling service, so on.. and lastly update `IsLoaded` to `true`.